# Is this recursive?

Tags: recursion

I came across this formula in a neuroscience journal:

$x = [sigma(y - z)] - w$

where:

$z = a + \max(x)$

My question is, can you solve for $x$ if $x$ is a constituent of $z$?

Comment: What does $\max(x)$ identify? $\max$ usually referres to the maximum value within a set.

Comment: max(x) is the maximum values across all x.

Comment: What are $a,x,y,z,w$ ?